# TFS API not working in ASP.NET MVC application when running in IIS and connecting to Visual Studio Online

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application which connects to TFS. The application is showing the tree with test plans, suites and testcases.

When the application is running in Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 everything works OK when connecting to the TFS instance installed on my development machine or when connecting to Visual Studio Online. When I deploy the ASP MVC application on my local IIS it still works when connecting to my local TFS. However when connecting to Visual Studio Online the TFS API is giving me the error 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.' when I am fetching the entries under a test plan, when accessing ITestPlan.RootSuite.Entries.

What could be the problem or a solution?

Some more info:

I am referencing the following assemblies, all version 11.0.0.0

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll

When running in Visual Studio the ASP MVC application is running in IISExpress and its loading the following assemblies (according to output window):

GAC_MSIL

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll

GAC_32

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll

When running in IIS, the following assemblies are loaded (according to Process Monitor):

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\

- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Diff.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.ni.dll
- Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.ni.dll

C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\

- Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll

The difference is that IISExpress loads the MSIL version of the assembly and IIS loads the native image. And IIS loads VersionControl assemblies and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll, and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Diff.ni.dll instead of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll. This seems strange to me and I can not explain this.

When running in IIS talking to the local TFS or TFS Online, the same assemblies are loaded. The only conclusion I can draw from this is that the data coming back from the server is different. But this conclusion conflicts with the fact that in IISExpress the web application can process TFS Online data.

Comment: Is it failing on the first TFS call, or a subsequent call?

Comment: I check whether ITestPlan.RootSuite or ITestPlan.RootSuite.Entries are null, but appareantly when checking this or doing the foreach loop on ITestPlan.RootSuite.Entries something makes an invalid call and throw this exception.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if it fails on the first TFS call or not. If it fails on the first call, then it's a problem with _all_ TFS calls.

Comment: I think misunderstood you. I manage to log in and get all testplans within a project. So getting the entries under the testplan is not the first call to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

This was the only post I could find related to a similar problem I had, I thought I would share the solution I found. I'm making a web app to generate XML from TFS changesets linked to a specific projects version. I ran into a problem where the web app I had created would run in IIS Express from visual studio but when set up in IIS it failed when I used something from the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client" namespace. After a while of struggling without the VS debug tools (I'm fairly new to coding there was probably a proper way to debug) I found I was getting a "TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://(server)" error.

Anyway the solution:
In IIS go to your application pool-advanced settings-process model-identity and change it to custom account, setting your username and password to your TFS username and password.

I know this is an old post and this may not be the problem the original poster had but I thought I would post it anyway in case it helps someone.